# PowerBI Scatterplot Y- Axis in other direction n...1

Tags: powerbi, scatter-plot

is it possible in the scatterplots (Point Diagramm) of PowerBI to change the Y-axis into the direction n..1 instead 1..n?

[image]
Bests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default Power BI Scatterplot visual, you can't change the axis order to for example 10 to 1. Other default visuals have the same limitation. I have tried the custom visuals and some offer the ability to define the start and end ranges of the axis, but don't seem to be able to do it either. The only other option would be to use a R or Python visual and visualization library that may allow you to have more control over the axis, for example ggplot